# add something while next button is delayed

Tags: javascript, delay, survey

I am programming a survey online and want to delay the next button. I have the following code but I would like to improve it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.submit_div").slideUp(00).delay(10000).fadeIn(1000);

});
</script>"
```

I have two ideas, and will appreciate code for any of them:
-Is there any way to add a text that says "please note the button will appear in 10 seconds" while the button is being delayed?
-Is it possible to disable the button and present it with opacity, until the count down finishes and makes it possible to click it?

Comment: Is the 'next' button a form submit button or a normal button with JS code associated with its click?

Comment: If I was taking an online survey that was being delayed 10 seconds at a time (per question?), I wouldn't be completing said online survey.

Comment: I am using it for a few only text pages, not for questions.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it with success callback in animation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.submit_div").slideUp(00, function() {           
      /*
          disable button here using `prop('disable',true)`
          and do the rest 
      */
    }).delay(10000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
      /*
          enable button here using `prop('disable',false)`
          and do the rest 
      */
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner on this. Is there any way to still see the button but having it unactivated?

Comment: @valeria : set disabled property using `prop('disable',true)`

Comment: where in the code I need to add this? Does that disable the button but still make it visible?

Comment: @valeria https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$("div.submit_div")` to be the said button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("div.submit_div").hide();
      setTimeout(function() {
           $("#init_text").remove();
           $("div.submit_div").show();
      }, 10000);
});
```

You can make one more div which shows the text you wanted to show while the button is hidden and manipulate that div similar to submit_div button.

Add `<div id="init_text"> Please complete survey</div>` before the code for the submit button.

Comment: I am completely begginer, do you know how I can add the code on the same space the button will appear?

Comment: Still don't understand where in the code I need to add the text, and how I make it appear before the next button is shown

Comment: You will be having a <button class="submit_div">submit</div>(or something similar), right? Add the div which I gave in answer before that.

Comment: Sorry, I have never used this language before, the code I posted before is all I have and I believe there is nothis that says "<button class="submit_div">submit</div>"

Comment: You must have a div with class submit_dev. You gave only script part of your html code. Please give complete html so that I can help you.